# Automatically backup JailBreak iPhone DCIM photo directory

Tags: iphone, ios, launchd, jailbreak

Hi I heard that you can write cron job into plist and put it to JB iPhone /Library/LaunchDaemons folder in plist format

I would like to backup the photo folder every 300 seconds, so I put a com.backup.plist like this into /Library/LaunchDaemons folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <true/>

    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.backup</string>

    <key>Program</key>
    <string>/bin/cp</string>

    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>-u</string>
        <string>/private/var/mobile/Media/DCIM/100APPLE/*.*</string>
        <string>/private/var/backup</string>
    </array>

    <key>StartInterval</key>
    <integer>300</integer>

</dict>
</plist>
```

I have created a folder of /private/var/backup with access right of 777 mobile:mobile

I rebooted the iPhone, however, the script just doesn't work

Does the failure refer to the "cp" command access right?
or should I change the /private/var/backup folder access right to something else?

btw I'm running iOS 4.3.3 Jailbreak iPhone 4

Many thanks for reading

Comment: Do you get any error messages in the log files?

Comment: where will the log file of launchdaemons be located?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the `man lanuchctl`

> Note that per-user configuration files
>   (LaunchAgents) must be owned by the
>   user loading them. All system-wide
>   daemons (LaunchDaemons) must be owned
>   by root. Configuration files must not
>   be group- or world-writable. These
>   restrictions are in place for security
>   reasons, as allowing writability to a
>   launchd configuration file allows one
>   to specify which executable will be
>   launched.

So,

```
chown root  /Library/LaunchDaemons/your.plist 
chgrp wheel /Library/LaunchDaemons/your.plist 
chmod 644   /Library/LaunchDaemons/your.plist
```

and after these:

```
launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/your.plist
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [Wikipedia's article on cp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cp_%28Unix%29):

> To copy a directory to a directory (-r or -R must be used)

So try adding `<string>-r</string>` to the list of arguments. Reboot your device and after 5 minutes (300 seconds) check if it worked.

Ad@m

Comment: since running `code` cp -u /private/var/mobile/Media/DCIM/100APPLE/*.* /private/var/backup `code` directly in shell has no problem copying the files, so I believe the problem isn't about the argument of cp